# How to change database type for @Lob property with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a requirement to make our application to work with Postgresql, Oracle and SQL Server. All is working fine in all 3 database except the @Lob mapping in a string property. For Oracle and SQLServer is working correctly (varchar(max) and clob) but for Postgresql what I want is the text type but it's being mapping as oid.

What i've done is create a dialect for Postgresql and overwrite getTypeName and remapSqlTypeDescriptor

```
@Override
public String getTypeName(int code, long length, int precision, int scale) throws HibernateException {
    if (code == Types.CLOB) {
        return super.getTypeName(Types.VARCHAR, length, precision, scale);
    }
    return super.getTypeName(code, length, precision, scale);

}

@Override
public SqlTypeDescriptor remapSqlTypeDescriptor(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor) {
    if (sqlTypeDescriptor.getSqlType() == Types.CLOB) {
        return VarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    }
    return super.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(sqlTypeDescriptor);
}
```

Are there any better way for doing this?

Property in entity

```
@Size(max = 300000)
@Column(name = "value")
@Lob
private String value;
```

and with this mapping i get the same result

```
@Size(max = 300000)
@Column(name = "value")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType")
@Lob
private String value;
```

Create sentence from Hibernate:
`org.hibernate.SQL : create table table (id int4 not null, value oid, primary key (id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have answered on several other questions almost just like this one, don't use `@Lob` for this. Just use `@Column(length=SOME_BIG_NUMBER)`.

`@Lob` means: use JDBC `Clob` APIs to read/write the string.

But you don't need that. You're (so I suppose) just abusing `@Lob` to make Hibernate's schema exporter generate the column type you want. That's *not* the semantic of `@Lob`. And anyway, Hibernate (6, and I believe 5 as well) will *automatically* pick a sensible column type if you just specify the length of the column, so that's unnecessary.

> What i've done is create a dialect for Postgresql and overwrite getTypeName and remapSqlTypeDescriptor

Do not do this please; this is just a silly thing to do. You're just redefining `@Lob` to mean "regular string handling". Just get rid of the `@Lob` annotation instead.

**UPDATE:** So it appears the actual real problem is that Hibernate 5 used the deprecated `long` data type for long strings *on Oracle*. That is to say, the problem was not with the dialect for Postgres, but with the dialect for Oracle. This was actually something I fixed in Hibernate 6 almost exactly three years ago to the day, but for reasons of backward compatibility cannot be changed in H5.

But no matter, it should be *very* easy to change the type mapping for long strings in a custom subclass of `OracleXyDialect`. Just write something like:

```
registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, "clob" );
```

This is much more straightforward than trying to make `@Lob` mean not-a-lob on Postgres.

(I have not tested this.)

Or, you could simply migrate to Hibernate 6 where this and *many other* issues with the dialects have already been sorted out.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried this approach and Oracle is generating this column as "long" and the data is inserted ok but when i make a select Hibernate is throwing a GenericJDBCException (SQL Error: 17027, SQLState: 99999 and HHH000327: Error performing load command) and for this reason i was trying with @Lob annotation because Hibernate is generating the column as clob

Comment: OK, so it would have been nice if you had included *that* information in your original post! This is Hibernate 5, then?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a suggestion for how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry for that! I've forgot because i was focused with the solution i found. Yes, it's hibernate 5.6.9. Another thing i tried was create my own custom type and in the creation check which db i'm working with and create the data type i want. With Oracle creating the org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor ends with "long" column type (the same as if i put the length in the column annotation as you suggested me)

Comment: I believe you should be fine if you just create a custom dialect for Oracle that reproduces the behavior of H6: i.e. uses `clob` as the column type when the length is too long for `varchar2`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi again! I haven't seen your update before my last comment, sorry. I confirm that is generating the column with the correct data type and the application is working correctly. So easy solution... I feel ashamed! Thanks for your time!
Hi again! I haven't seen your update before my last comment, sorry. I confirm that is generating the column with the correct data type and the application is working correctly. So easy solution... I feel ashamed! Thanks for your time!
I will suggest update to Hibernate 6 but my company is not prone to upgrade.

Comment: Cheers, it's good to know it you got it working.

Comment: @GavinKing you probably mean `registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARCHAR, "clob" );`?